# Clustering algorithm using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, algorithm, sorting

I have a set of data:

```
{ name: 'item1', timeOfDay: '36000', dayOfWeek: '1', dayOfMonth: '15',  room: '1'}
{ name: 'item2', timeOfDay: '3600',  dayOfWeek: '2', dayOfMonth: '10',  room: '2'}
{ name: 'item1', timeOfDay: '18000', dayOfWeek: '3', dayOfMonth: '20',  room: '3'}
{ name: 'item3', timeOfDay: '72000', dayOfWeek: '4', dayOfMonth: '5',   room: '4'}
```

Given a new item i'm looking for an algorithm to find the closest items order by distance

```
{ name: 'item2', timeOfDay: '36000', dayOfWeek: '5', dayOfMonth: '3',  room: '2'}
```

First I looked at kMeans to organise items around centers but I have the feeling I need something sorting the item at the good location.

Multicriteria sort ? but that could learn which criteria is the stronger ?

I don't want to do Array.sort() because:

- I need to add a new item without sorting all the array
- I need to merge same (closest) values

Comment: www.breezejs.com might be helpful is this case

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "closest item"? How is that measured?

Comment: Well, in my new implementation I use a SortedSet with a comparator. But I chose the implementation, I assume a clustering algorithm (like kmean) can find closest value